# Android RecyclerView - IndexOutOfBounds exception in onBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I remove an item from my `RecyclerView` like this:

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) { 
    final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(); //get position which is swipe

    if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {    //if swipe left
        activeSubs.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, activeSubs.size());
        saveListToSharedPrefs();
        updateCost();
    }
}
```

Where `activeSubs` is an `ArrayList<>` of custom objects.

When I remove an element from the list, the app crashes and this is my logcat:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
                      at com.dancam.subscriptions.ActiveSubscriptions.ActiveSubsRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ActiveSubsRecyclerAdapter.java:58)
```

`ActiveSubsRecyclerAdapter.java:58` - this line points to the first line of my `onBindViewHolder()` that looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ActiveViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {
    Subscription sub = activeSubsList.get(pos);
    viewHolder.title.setText(sub.getTitle());
    viewHolder.cycle.setText(cycleArray[sub.getCycle()]);
    viewHolder.duration.setText(durationArray[sub.getDuration()]);
    viewHolder.price.setText(String.valueOf(sub.getPrice()).concat(currency.getSymbol()));
    viewHolder.firstBill.setText(sub.getFirstPayment());
    viewHolder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources()
                .getColor(sub.getColor()));
    viewHolder.expandableLayout.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources()
                .getColor(sub.getColor()));
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(sub.getImage()).into(viewHolder.image);
}
```

I tried setting a breakpoint on this line and this is the debug output:

[image: debug output]

Any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: As the error and the screenshot you posted clearly show, `activeSubsList` is empty. You can't `get` an element from an empty list.

Comment: Also, please post all relevant information as text.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes I see that, but I don't have to get any element actually. If the list is empty I need to display an empty list, onBindViewHolder, shouldn't be called at all I think

Comment: @Carcigenicate can't actually post the debug stuff as text. Android Studio does not let me copy it

Comment: Well you are trying to when you write `activeSubsList.get(pos);`, and you must be entering the function if the breakpoint was activated. If you want to see why the function was entered, the debugging tool will almost definitely have a tool to examine the stack.

Comment: Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after removing the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two different lists here. One is `activeSubs` and the other is `activeSubsList`. Which one you're using for populating your `RecyclerView`?

Anyway, you need to use one `ArrayList` to be populated in your `RecyclerView` so that you can track the status of that `ArrayList` and update your `RecyclerView` accordingly with the `notifyDataSetChanged()` calls.

I suggest to use the `activeSubs` list only and use it in the `onBindViewHolder` function as well when you're getting something from your list.

As your `onBindViewHolder` is getting called, so I assume your `getCount()` function returns the size of `activeSubs` which is not actually empty and hence the call in `onBindViewHolder` is getting an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

So I'm just re-writing some of your code below.

```
if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {    //if swipe left
    activeSubs.remove(position);
    saveListToSharedPrefs();
    updateCost();

    // Only calling notifyDataSetChanged should do the job
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now in your `onBindViewHolder` function you need to get the object from your `activeSubs` list.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ActiveViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {
    Subscription sub = activeSubs.get(pos);
    // ... Here goes the other code
}
```

And the `getCount` function should return the size of the `activeSubs` list.

```
public int getItemCount () {
    return (activeSubs != null) ? activeSubs.size() : 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've worked and debugged the error. But it's getting stranger and stranger. First of all `activeSubs` and `activeSubsList` are actually the same thing, only the variable name is different (not quite elegant, I know, but I need to keep them separate). I've noticed that when I remove an element from the list, it gets correctly removed and the list gets correctly saved to shared preferences, because when I relaunch the app after crash, the element I removed isn't there anymore. Another thing. The error occurs always, not only when I remove the last element from the list.

Comment: I think you haven't understood my answer then. When you're dealing with `RecyclerView` then you need to work with a single list and if you're adjusting your `RecyclerView` based on that list it'll work just fine. You might also consider having another list to serve your other purposes. Did you try the changes I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I use this method in my BaseAdapter

```
public void removeItemAt(int position) {

    if (getItemCount() > 0 && position < getItemCount()) {

        getItems().remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "not in bounds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Also, return 0 if items are null.

```
 public int getItemCount () {

     if (items == null) {
         return 0;
     }

     return items.size();
 }
```

And, I usually return if pos is wrong in onBindViewHolder()

```
if (getItemCount() <= 0 && position >= getItemCount()) {
    return;
}
```